# "Changed On/Modified" columns - Date Format & Regional Settings

Tags: 2007, list, calculated-column, date-time, regional-settings

I was wondering if I change my regional settings through: Site Settings - Regional Settings - Locale: Dutch (Netherlands), affects the date format of the standard columns (Changed On/Modified e.g.).

I want the format to be 'dd-mm-yyyy'.

Or should I work with a calculated field or another option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(comment) I don't know in detail on 2007, but here in 2010 it changed how you said. But it is site-wide, so I need to change it site by site. And it changes every date column of my lists too.

Comment: As I checked that, it does not changed the dates in the lists in my SP 2010 environment.

Comment: But you can access these settings? And your columns are from basic content type "Date & Time"? Because I tested it with different rights and as long as I could access these regional setting, I could get the effect.

Comment: A late answer but indeed these settings did the trick, it changes the format of the dates in the lists. I sorted this out that it was an internal problem with a custom kind of list web part where the date comes through in another format then the regional settings.